# python загрузка файлов vk

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Подключил VK API. Необходимо сделать отправку файлов на сервер как о этом рассказано на этой странице - http://vk.com/dev/upload_files
P.S. Загрузка файлов на стену пользователя

```
import vk
from time import sleep
import sys
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import base64
import requests

vkapi = vk.API(access_token='token', app_id='id')
sleep(0.5)

data = vkapi.photos.getWallUploadServer(user_id="72374405")
DATA_USER_ID = data['user_id']
DATA_ALBUM_ID = data['album_id']
DATA_UPLOAD_URL = data['upload_url']

#with open("1.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    #fileD = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())


#files = {'1.jpg': open('1.jpg', 'rb')}
#r = requests.post(DATA_UPLOAD_URL, files=files)
#r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
#print(r)
#html = r.read().decode("utf-8")

#dataP = '1.jpg'
dataP = "photo=" + dataP#.encode("ASCII")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(DATA_UPLOAD_URL,dataP)
html = response.read().decode("utf-8")
print (html)
```

решеткой помечено то, что пробовал но не сработало, либо не подошло.

Вроде как корректно отработался вариант с

```
files = {'1.jpg': open('1.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(DATA_UPLOAD_URL, files=files)
r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
print(r)
#html = r.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Однако в таком случае не работает вывод и тем самым я не могу понять, отработался ли должным образом запрос.

В случае успешного завершения кода выхлоп таков:

```
{"server":622624,"photo":"[]","hash":"8112ae8847b27fb1cdf678d3d168e6ae"}
```

То есть загрузка изображения провальная.

Может кто-либо смог или и так знает как загрузить файл на сервер ВК через POST на Python3. Поделитесь опытом, советом, замечанием. Если что-то в коде непонятно - пишите; отвечу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот мой вариант размещения фотографии на стене сообщества от имени сообщества. Реализован алгоритм, описанный [в официальной документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=2.%2B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%2B%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%2B%D0%BD%D0%B0%2B%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83):

```
# Импортируем необходимые модули
import vk
import requests

# Задаём идентификатор группы, токен доступа, картинку и её описание
group_id = 'my_group_id'
access_token = 'my_access_token'
filename = 'image.jpg'
caption = 'Some text'

# Авторизуемся в VK
session = vk.Session(access_token=access_token)
vk_api = vk.API(session)

# Получаем адрес сервера для загрузки картинки
upload_url = vk_api.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=group_id)['upload_url']

# Формируем данные параметров для сохранения картинки на сервере
request = requests.post(upload_url, files={'photo': open(filename, "rb")})
params = {'server': request.json()['server'],
          'photo': request.json()['photo'],
          'hash': request.json()['hash'],
          'group_id': group_id}

# Сохраняем картинку на сервере и получаем её идентификатор
photo_id = vk_api.photos.saveWallPhoto(**params)[0]['id']

# Формируем параметры для размещения картинки в группе и публикуем её
params = {'attachments': photo_id,
          'message': caption,
          'owner_id': '-' + group_id,
          'from_group': '1'}
vk_api.wall.post(**params)
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, комментарии к вашему коду. Пока-что не совсем понятно что и где проихсодит.

Comment: Добавил комментарии.

Comment: Воспользовался вашим кодом, но на вызове метода saveWallPhoto получаю ошибку 121. Invalid hash. Может сталкивались и подскажите в чём проблема ? Код полностью идентичный вашему, единственное отличие - добавил в params для saveWallPhoto версию апи (сейчас требует как обязательное поле). Стек-трейс: vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 121. Invalid hash. request_params = {'oauth': '1', 'method': 'photos.saveWallPhoto', 'server': '834404', 'photo': '[{"photo":"43ed0:z","sizes":[["s",89,"da1c1","uzrKc",75,56]],"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"kid":"7e79f7"}]', 'hash': 'd5c8', 'group_id': '*******', 'v': '5.73'}

Comment: Очень странно, так как в моём скрипте прямо сейчас работает  именно этот код без каких-либо изменений и дополнений. И у меня всё работает даже без передачи версии API.

Comment: Я давно не проверял работу скрипта и оказалось, что он 1 марта перестал работать. Действительно, во всех вызовах потребовалось добавить версию API и изменить формат передаваемых данных в attachments, так как теперь одного только photo_id недостаточно.

Answer (score 7):

Есть библиотека [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api), у нее есть вспомогательный класс для загрузки файлов [VkUpload](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/43539bf2174e40bef910c7d1334a9194088aadf9/vk_api/upload.py), а у него есть нужный метод [photo_wall](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/43539bf2174e40bef910c7d1334a9194088aadf9/vk_api/upload.py#L149).

Добавляю пример использования ([ссылка на полный скрипт с картинками](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f1409adcb44c8dcb88efbdc39da45c3e6f6f5757/vk_api__examples/simple_wall.post_local_image/main.py)):

```
import vk_api
from vk_api import VkUpload

login, password = '<login>', '<password>'

# Авторизация
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
vk_session.auth()

upload = VkUpload(vk_session)  # Для загрузки изображений

# Загрузка картинок на сервера вк и получение их id
photos = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg']
photo_list = upload.photo_wall(photos)
attachment = ','.join('photo{owner_id}_{id}'.format(**item) for item in photo_list)

# Добавление записи на стену
vk_session.method("wall.post", {
    'owner_id': None,  # Посылаем себе на стену
    'message': 'Test!',
    'attachment': attachment,
})
```

Вот так будет выглядеть запись на стене:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Как-то разобрался :D

```
import vk
from time import sleep
import sys
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import base64
import requests
import json

vkapi = vk.API(access_token='token', app_id='app_id')
sleep(0.5)

data = vkapi.photos.getWallUploadServer(user_id="72374405")
DATA_USER_ID = data['user_id']
DATA_ALBUM_ID = data['album_id']
DATA_UPLOAD_URL = data['upload_url']

r = requests.post(DATA_UPLOAD_URL, files={'photo': open('1.jpg',"rb")})
r.status_code == requests.codes.ok
params = {'server': r.json()['server'], 'photo': r.json()['photo'], 'hash': r.json()['hash']}
wallphoto = vkapi.photos.saveWallPhoto(**params)
#attachments.append(wallphoto[0]['id'])
photoID = wallphoto[0]['id']

params = {'attachments': 'photo' + '72374405_' + str(photoID), 'message': 'Test'}
params['owner_id'] = '72374405'
print(params)
vkapi.wall.post(**params)
```

Позже уже буду разбираться во всем этом коде и делать его более читаемым. Главное что он сейчас работает :)

Comment: .....
на версии 2 работать будет ?
мда

Comment: Лучше в ответе (и в вопросах) удалять ненужный код: закомментированный, не имеющий смысла в текущем контексте, не используемые переменные (например `DATA_ALBUM_ID`), и т.п.