# Публикация фотографии по ссылке на стене VK

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте
Есть просто скрипт который постит запись текстовую на стену ВК :

```
import vk

my_app_id = ******
user_login = '******'
user_password = '*****'

session = vk.AuthSession(scope='wall', app_id=my_app_id, user_login=user_login,
                                         user_password=user_password)
vk.api.access_token = "*********************"
api = vk.API(session)
api.wall.post(owner_id='*****', message='Привет')
```

Нужно, чтобы к сообщению прикреплялось фото с ссылки. Читал документацию, но не полностью понял что к чему.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для произвольной картинки её надо вначле загрузить себе, а затем отправить в ВК https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444176/183314

Answer (score 1):

```
import vk
Session = vk.AuthSession(
    app_id='***', user_login='***', user_password='***', scope='wall,  groups'
)
vk_api = vk.API(Session)
vk_api.wall.post(
    owner_id=- '***',
    message='hello world',
    attachments='photo151911284_440710456'
) # Ссылка на ваше фото
```

Comment: На ссылке https://i.imgur.com/rv8ue.jpg не работает

Comment: @andreymal по сути никак взять картинку из этой ссылки, ибо нужно загружать посторонние файлы к ним на сервер, а для этого нужно скачивать картинку.

Answer (score 1):

Предложенный ниже скрипт скачает фотографию по указанному URL, загрузит во ВКонтакте и опубликует её на стене текущего пользователя.

```
import requests
import vk

IMAGE_URL = ...
ACCESS_TOKEN = ...

vkapi = vk.API(vk.Session(ACCESS_TOKEN))
destination = vkapi.photos.getWallUploadServer()
image = requests.get(IMAGE_URL, stream=True)
# имя файла значения не имеет, но без него ВК не принимает фотографию
data = ("image.jpg", image.raw, image.headers['Content-Type'])
meta = requests.post(destination['upload_url'], files={'photo': data}).json()
me = vkapi.users.get()[0]['uid']
photo = vkapi.photos.saveWallPhoto(user_id=me, **meta)[0]
vkapi.wall.post(user_id=me, attachments=photo['id'])
```

Подробнее о протоколе загрузки фотографии читайте в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=2.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83).